# Combine two InfluxDB rows into one - Flux query

Tags: influxdb, flux-influxdb

Hi I am currently doing this in R but would like to know if there is a way for me to do it in **Flux** instead:

I have a time series that tracks a value and only stores when the signal is turned on and off. The problem is that the nature of the machine I am tracking only allows for it to be done this way. This results in a data table/measurement where two rows kind of display a single value (e.g. the start and end of a Fault). **How do I query the data using flux to combine those two rows?** (With "start" and "stop" as tags/fields)

I currently use the `elapsed()`-function to calculate the time difference/duration of my value

```
time                      value     field          measurement    equipmentNumber    workplace    duration
2021-01-29 07:11:17.496   1         FAULT_LASER    FAULT_LASER    L5211M0855         0            188
2021-01-29 07:12:03.332   0         FAULT_LASER    FAULT_LASER    L5211M0855         0            45835
2021-01-29 07:12:19.618   1         FAULT_LASER    FAULT_LASER    L5211M0855         0            16285
2021-01-29 07:12:19.618   0         FAULT_LASER    FAULT_LASER    L5211M0855         0            161725
```

Im am doing this in R at the moment:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df_f)){
  if(df_f[i, "duration"] > 0){
    df_fdur[i, "start"] <- df_f[i, "time"]
    df_fdur[i, "stop"] <- df_f[i+1, "time"]
    df_fdur[i, "type"] <- df_f[i, "value"]
    df_fdur[i, "duration"] <- df_f[i, "duration"]
    df_fdur[i, "workplace"] <- df_f[i, "workplace"]
    df_fdur[i, "equipmentNumber"] <- df_f[i, "equipmentNumber"]
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can do that?

Comment: Duplicate: https://community.influxdata.com/t/combine-two-rows/19500

Comment: I want to excuse for the community here. Members here tend to miss manners sometimes. Great solution. Thanks for sharing. Logged in, just to vote you up and comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not directly solve the question but it solved the problem I was working on. Maybe it is useful for someone else. Have a great day!

```
// Get all the data from the bucket filtered for FAULT_LASER
data = from(bucket: "plcview_4/autogen")
  |> range(start: 2021-01-29T00:00:00.000Z, stop: now())                // regular time range filter
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "FAULT_LASER")                 // filter for the measurement
  |> elapsed(unit: 1ms, timeColumn: "_time", columnName: "duration")    // calculate time difference between rows
  |> yield(name: "data")
// returns data tables for every unique set of tags (workplace and equipmentNumber)

// Filter for all "No-Fault-Values" and sum their durations
operational = data
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._value == 0)   // filter for all rows where FAULT_LASER = 0 --> No Faults
  |> group()                            // group all data tables together
  |> sum(column: "duration")            // sum all the durations from all data tables 
  |> yield(name: "operational")

// Count the number of faults
nfaults = data
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._value == 1)   // filter for all rows where FAULT_LASER = 1 --> Faults
  |> group()                            // group all data tables together
  |> count()                            // count the number of records
  |> yield(name: "nfaults")
```